# How to run command in screen without opening screen?

Tags: bash, display, minecraft

I want to develop a bash script, which reads out usernames, which should be whitelisted on a Minecraft Server. This server is running on a screen called "Minecraft".

So now I need a screen command, which let me run a command in the screen without opening the screen.

If this wont work, is there a way to simulate crtl a + d to close the screen?

What I tried:

```
screen -d -m Minecraft -c "/whitelist add merfy69"
screen -S Minecraft -X "/whitelist add merfy69"
```

What i expect:
Adding user to whitelist without opening screen or closing the screen directly

Comment: `/whitelist add merfy69` does not look like a command your OS or `screen` could run. It looks like a command you *type* in some utility (like a Minecraft server that may run inside `screen`). I guess you don't want to "run command" like running an executable; you want to send input (like from a terminal) to an already running executable. Is this right?

Comment: Presubably you also want to send a newline at the end of the command. This is a common FAQ with `screen` I believe.

Comment: Hi @Kamil Maciorowski

yes I think that describes it very good